# Can I control which session I want to login at Grub loading?

Tags: grub2, gdm

Is there a way by which I can choose if I want to login to ubuntu(unity) or ubuntu classic at grub loading it self. 
I have autologin enabled and I want to choose the session at the starting. 
Or is there a way where I can change the script which is needed to load kernel and run other scripts which invokes gdm?

Comment: just change the autologin

Comment: Yes that can be done. but I want to select my window manager during boot. I want it to be choosable with grub itself.. alwaqys choosing autologin is a tedious process.

Comment: Not without hacking into some system files; copied from someone in chat: defaultsession is in /etc/gdm/custom.conf, but this will only be used if the user never chose a session himself, else it's in ~/.dmrc - so you gotta replace the key there (of course it's a mess when an init script changes user config files)...

Comment: Other suggestion: you can even have unity log in on tty7 and classic log in on tty6 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Ubuntu runlevels 2-5 are the same. Just modify runlevel 3 or 4 to achieve your needs. In GRUB, add a new line to it with your newly created runlevel.

In /etc directory, there are rcX.d directories, which controls services on different runlevels. As I see, rc3.d contains the same links as rc2.d to services in /etc/init.d, so create a new GRUB entry and put "3" at the and of the line without quotes (this will start your system on runlevel 3). Start this, set up a different graphical environment. After restart, this entry should meet your needs, I think.

Comment: Good idea! Please add a nice explanation on how to choose runlevels from GRUB and how to meddle with the config in /etc/init, so *you*'ll get some delicious karma and a good chance on the bounty ;)